# Booking dates calculations

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a simple web application with PHP / Laravel. It is a booking system, where you can book rooms. A single room, for each date can be booked more than one time, let's take 5 for example. On the database, I have a rooms table, and a bookings table. Obviously, the bookings are stored in the bookings table, and they contain start and end dates. With those two dates, I am calculating the date ranges which they are booked, so I can mark them with a different color in a calendar:

```
<?php

foreach($room->bookings as $booking) :
    $start_date = new DateTime($booking->start_date);
    $end_date = new DateTime($booking->end_date);
    $end_date = $end_date->modify('+1 day');

    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $end_date);

    foreach($daterange as $date) :

?>
        +new Date({{ $date->format("Y") }}, {{ $date->format("m") - 1 }}, {{ $date->format("d") }}), // This is javascript
<?php

    endforeach;

endforeach;

?>
```

Don't be confused from the code. The {{ }} braces are used to output the PHP variables. With what I've done until now, I can calculate the dates between the start_end date of each booking, and output those dates in the javascript plugin.

> What I want to do, is calculate which rooms are fully booked (a date
>   is booked to the limit, in this case 5 times as I stated before), and
>   which rooms are partially booked (2 or 3 times for a date). How can I
>   output the dates which appear more than 5 times, to another
>   `$booked_dates array`?

If I managed to do that, the other part would be easy. This is what I've tried, using variable variables (dynamic variables) from another question, but I've not been able to implement it successfully into my own code:

```
$repeated = array();
foreach($uid as $id){
    if (!isset($repeated[$id])) $repeated[$id] = -1;
    $repeated[$id]++;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you will need to query your database and get the counter you want, based on $room_id and $start_date (variables are an example here). The code you provided, as far as i can understand it, does not provide room info at all. It is used to create a calendar view.

Comment: I am already returning all the database info I need with the code I provided, I don't think there's any more need of database fetching. Now, that I got all the date ranges, all I need is an array with dates that have been booked 5 times. Nothing more.

Comment: you need dates related to particular room, not just any dates

Comment: Describe your bookings table and your rooms table

Comment: lets say you have 3 different rooms. Two rooms are totally available (5), and the third is partially booked (availability dropped to 3 from original 5). You need to be able to pair room and date.

Comment: My thinking is if you have a confirmed field that is an enum that return a 0 if not confirmed and 1 if confirmed then you can use it

Comment: @andrew I think I already have that. The code I provided, is inside another foreach(), which loops through every room, so I don't think I'll have a problem with that. The $daterange variable is unique for every room.

Comment: @JamesNjuguna Rooms: id, name, units (number of times that a date can be booked). Bookings: id, room_id (references id at rooms table), start_date, end_date.